# How to reduce spacing between 2 row in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I am making a Oracle APEX Interactive report with search criteria. But I have a number of search criteria, which come in 3 rows.

How can I reduce the spacing between the rows, so that the report looks compact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply CSS in your page to reduce the padding of each cell.

```
.a-IRR-tableContainer table td {padding-top:2px; padding-bottom: 2px;}
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. That works for me for the Interactive report . I also have a static region where I have few fields for search criteria. Can you help me know, how can I reduce the horizontal spacing between each field in the static region.

Comment: I was able to reduce the padding by using the template options --> Remove padding. And that works. My template type was :"Blank with Attributes (No Grid).

Comment: Use the browser inspect element tool to look for the classes relevant to each template. It may take some getting used to, but it's worth the investment. Also check out the APEX Theme roller.

Comment: It doesn't work well when there is a lot of data in the grid, because you see the standard padding first, and then when it loads you see the class padding (reduced)